# Creating serial text output with a text

Tags: c++

Hello I want to know how can I make a code like i want to input a number XXX it will output

ChinaXXX
BeijingXXX-CHINA-XXX
+180243189(XXX)

Like this. Advance thanks
Sorry for the title. I dont how can i said about on title.

Comment: Are all the tags relevant to your question? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Its my first time posting here. Sorry for tags. I thought there was 5 minimum tags to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
  std::string number;
  std::cin >> number;
  std::cout << "China" << number << " Beijing" << number
        << "-CHINA-" << number << " +180243189(" << number << ")"
        << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have C++20 available, use std::format

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string number;
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << std::format("China{0} Beijing{0}-CHINA-{0} +180243189({0})\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```